# Learning how to use ajax on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I am trying to understand the basics of AJAX and how to make database requests with it. But as I have never touched PHP in my life, I only work with Ruby on Rails.

Now all of the really basic guide about AJAX are written for thoes that do PHP it seems to me.
But are there any of which are for Ruby writers also?

I was following this page : http://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails
But the usage of AJAX was left a mistery for me in that example.

Like this for instance:

```
$("#product-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'delete') %>")
$("#product-modal").modal("show")
```

Have not seen anything like it in AJAX guide.

So yes...   Are there any nice guides for real AJAX beginners, who want to use it in Rail framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

The chapter from great Hartl's guide: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax